# After implementing hook_node_access, how to stop node from appearing in view?

Tags: views, 8

In Drupal 8, I implemented a `hook_node_access` function in my module to control access for a certain role under certain conditions and it works fine.

However, all of that content type are still shown on a view when the user views it. This is expected behavior according to the documentation:

> In node listings (lists of nodes generated from a select query, such as the default home page at path 'node', an RSS feed, a recent content block, etc.), ... hook_node_access() is not called on each node for performance reasons and for proper functioning of the pager system. When adding a node listing to your module, be sure to use an entity query, which will add a tag of "node_access". This will allow modules dealing with node access to ensure only nodes to which the user has access are retrieved, through the use of hook_query_TAG_alter(). See the Entity API topic for more information on entity queries.

[(Link)](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!node!node.module/group/node_access/8.2.x)

I understand why the view does not check each individual content, but I do not understand what this documentation is asking me to do to fix that. The documentation for `hook_query_TAG_alter` and on entity queries is not very helpful either.

How do I ensure that only items of this content type that the current user has view access to are shown in a view?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Views Search Ignoring Custom Node Access permissions](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/52756/views-search-ignoring-custom-node-access-permissions)

Answer (score 1):

having run into the same problem as you I hope I can save you a headache.
Depending on the amount of results you have I can provide 2 ways to tackle this:

**1. Works when you don't need pagination**

HOOK_views_post_execute. This will have the rows in the variable. In here you can check the access and unset() the rows not allowed.

**2. Works when you need pagination**

HOOK_views_query_alter. I've used this solution for a view I needed myself with around 10000 results. I do a custom permissions check based on the user and the groups they are part of. Baed on this I generate a list of ID's of nodes they user is allowed to see. I add these ID's as an "IN" query to the view:

```
$cond["field"] = "media_field_data.mid";
$cond["operator"] = "IN";
$query->addWhere('1', $cond["field"], $mids, $cond["operator"]);
```

Where **$mids** has all the allowed Mids in there.
Hope this helps you get along!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when using a custom hook_ENTITY_TYPE_access

... just putting an example here to save people time:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_post_execute().
*/
function MODULE_views_post_execute(ViewExecutable $view) {
  if ($view->id() == 'view_name') {
   $result = $view->result;
   $account = $view->getUser();
   $user = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('user')->load($account->id());
   $filter_results = [];
   foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
     $entity = $value->_entity;
       /// opp can be create, view, delete, update. 
       if ($entity->access('view', $user) == TRUE) {
        $filter_results[$key] = $value;
     }
   }
   $view->result = $filter_results;
  }
 }
```