# How to filter a view according to nodes permissions

Tags: views, users

I would like my view to not display nodes to which the current user does not have access to.

I have implemented hook_permission "access nodes of type mytype"

I have also implemented hook_node_access this way:

```
function mymodule_node_access( $node, $op, $account)
{

   if ($op == 'create')
    {
     $type = $node;                                                                                                                            
    }

   else
   {

    switch($node->type)
    {
      case "mytype":
        if ( !user_access("access nodes of type mytype") )
         {return NODE_ACCESS_DENY;}
        break;
    }

   }

 return NODE_ACCESS_IGNORE;
}
```

I set up the view to displays only nodes of type "mytype". 
When a user who does not have the permission "access nodes of type mytype" clicks on a link in the rows of the view, he gets the page "access denied" which is what I want. 
But I also want the view to not display the nodes of type "mytype" if a user does not have the permission to "access nodes of type mytype".

How do I implement that?

Thanks,

Baba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer is actually [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/52756/views-search-ignoring-custom-node-access-permissions?rq=1).

> It seems that a better way to control node access is through hook_node_access_records and hook_node_grants as described here http://drupal.org/node/1260948. This works with views properly.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Node access example](http://api.drupal.org/api/examples/node_access_example!node_access_example.module/group/node_access_example/7), you can manage to make it work with [Node access](https://drupal.org/project/node_access) module.

> The modules provide roles and user specific security permissions for
>   menus, menu items, nodes, and security integration into the
>   administration and help systems.

Comment: I did actually look at the node access example and the code I posted above is as much as I could take from it because Node access example does not seem to use views to display nodes. Therefore I haven't found a way to do the same thing with a view.