# How to get the nodeid in node_grants so that it works in a view?

Tags: views

I am exploring the node_grants and node_access_records with the following objective:

I want to be able to hide nodes where the current logged-in user is not 'friends' with the node author. The node author selects if they want to limit it to friends or not with a boolean field. Here, the subtlety is that there are a few views which list nodes on my site, so I want it to work for views too.

I am using drupal 7, user relationships for the 'friends' relationship and here is my node_grants code. How do I get the node id, especially in the context of views?

```
function mymod_access_node_grants($account, $op) {
// Grants all rights if the author
$grants['mymod_access_author'] = array($account->uid);

    $value_friends = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_friends_only');
    $value_friends = $value_friends[0]["value"];
    $value_friends = 1;

    if ( $value_friends == NULL) {
        $value_friends = 0;
    }
    if ($value_friends == 0) {
        $grants['mymod_access_public'] = array(1);
        $grants['mymod_access_friends'] = array(1);
        $grants['mymod_access_notfriends'] = array(1);

    } else if ($value_friends == 1)  {
        //if node is for friends only, then check if relationship exists...
        $current_user_uid = $account->uid;
        $node_author_uid = $node->uid;

        // Set up the parameters
        $params = array('between' => array($current_user_uid, $node_author_uid));

        // Get the relationships
        $relationships = user_relationships_load($params);

        if ($relationships) {
            $grants['mymod_access_public'] = array(2);
            $grants['mymod_access_friends'] = array(2);
            $grants['mymod_access_notfriends'] = array(2);
        } else {
            $grants['mymod_access_public'] = array(3);
            $grants['mymod_access_friends'] = array(3);
            $grants['mymod_access_notfriends'] = array(3);
        }
    } else {
    } 
}

return $grants;
}
```

- PS: although I have $node in my code, it is empty at the moment!

Answer (score 1):

You actually need to implement two hooks:

- [`hook_node_grants()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_grants/7) which returns the grants a user has
- [`hook_node_access_records()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_access_records/7) which returns the grants a node needs

It's the second hook that gets a node object, not the first. Keep in mind that you need to implement both the hooks.

As for [`hook_node_access()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_access/7), this hook is called when a node is fully loaded, and it not called for node listings, as reported in the documentation.

> Also note that this function isn't called for node listings (e.g., RSS feeds, the default home page at path 'node', a recent content block, etc.) See [Node access rights](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/group/node_access/7) for a full explanation.

As for views, a view doesn't full load a node, but executes a SQL query to get node data. [merlinofchaos](https://www.drupal.org/u/merlinofchaos) clearly states it in [Views does not respect hook_node_access](https://www.drupal.org/node/1266388#comment-5486394).

> `hook_node_access()` is something that is run after a node is fully loaded. Since Views is loading nodes via query, you can't get the query to respect it unless you also use `hook_db_rewrite_sql()` which is what Views hooks into.
>
> This is not true of just Views, but *any* query that loads nodes. For example, the default Drupal front page will not respect `hook_node_access()` that isn't paired with `hook_db_rewrite_sql()` any better.
>
> `hook_node_grants()` and `hook_node_access_records()` will be used, however, if you set "Disable SQL rewriting" then you are specifically skipping that stuff.

Notice that [`hook_db_rewrite_sql()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!hooks!core.php/function/hook_db_rewrite_sql/6) is not used from Drupal 7 and higher, though. The equivalent for Drupal 7 and higher is `hook_query_alter()`.

Comment: Thanks Kiamlaluno.
I do have both functions, it's just that node_grants tells which nodes the current user can see or not in the end. Can I create for a same realm many grant-ids? For example, for a 'friends_realm', have grant ids be the $uid of each of these friends?

Comment: No, `hook_node_grants()` returns the grant IDs associated with the passed account. They aren't node IDs, but integers; if they are IDs, they could be user IDs, such as in `$grants['example_author'] = array($account->uid);`. Yes, you can return more grant IDs for the same realm, as in `$grants['node_access_test'] = array(8888, 8889);`.

Comment: Hi Kiamlaluno, my question was in the opposite way: when you create the grants for nodes in node_Access_records, can you provide multiple values of the grant ids for the same realm? For example, if following the example on the Drupal function page: `code`$grants[] = array('realm' =>'example_author','gid' => $node->uid,'grant_view' => 1,'grant_update' => 1,'grant_delete' => 1,'priority' => 0,);`code`

Comment: With the Book access module, I used multiple grant IDs for the same realm; so, yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the hook you must use in your case is hook_node_access https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_access/7
which is fired every time a node is requested and thus the $node variable is not provided by the system and is not empty

Comment: `hook_node_access()` doesn't work with a view because it is never invoked with a list of nodes, such as in the case of a view. See the code invoking that hook.

Comment: seems like a bug that has been fixed. See here https://www.drupal.org/node/1266388 and here http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/23225/having-views-respect-hook-node-access

Comment: No, it has not been fixed. merlinofchaos clearly states that the Views module doesn't respect `hook_node_access()` since that hook is invoked when a full node is loaded, which is not what the Views module does.

Comment: Thanks both for your contribution. I have looked a lot on the web, and it does seem like the only way to get Views to respect access to nodes is through the node_Grants and node_access_records...