# Exclude specific nodes from a view based on role permissions

Tags: 8, views, nodes

I am using [View access per node](https://www.drupal.org/project/vapn) to hide certain nodes from the general public and allow specific roles to view it, which is simple and works like a charm.

The issue is that those nodes are shown, even when browsing with anonymous user. I can't find a way for the view to identify the "View access per node" status for each row.

I thought to change my approach; I was looking through the [Comparison and Overview of Access Control modules](https://www.drupal.org/node/270000), but any non-deprecated option available in Drupal 8 seems an overkill for this case.

Comment: [Views does not respect hook_node_access](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/23225/having-views-respect-hook-node-access) which is what this module uses. Module creator should've used `hook_node_access_records` along with `hook_node_grants` instead. You could do [comment #3](https://www.drupal.org/project/vapn/issues/3058989#comment-13256022) as a workaround.

Comment: Beside the Views module (which is part of Drupal core since Drupal 8), other core modules don't use `hook_node_access()` for a page listing entities. That's a general behavior you will find in Drupal core.

Comment: @NoSssweat it's good enough for this. Please copy your comment into an answer so I can mark it as accepted and upvote it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Views does not respect `hook_node_access`](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/23225/having-views-respect-hook-node-access) which is what this module uses. Module creator should've used `hook_node_access_records` along with `hook_node_grants` instead.

You could try [comment #3](https://www.drupal.org/project/vapn/issues/3058989#comment-13256022) as a workaround.

> ```
> /**
>  * Implements hook_views_pre_render().
>  */
> function example_views_pre_render(ViewExecutable $view) {
>   $user = \Drupal::currentUser();
>   $vapn_config = \Drupal::service('config.factory')->get('vapn.vapnconfig');
>   $vapn_node_types = $vapn_config->get('vapn_node_list');
>
>   foreach ($view->result as $key => $row) {
>     if ($row->_entity) {
>       $is_vapn_bundle = FALSE;
>       if ($bundle = $row->_entity->bundle()) {
>         $is_vapn_bundle = in_array($bundle, $vapn_node_types);
>       }
>
>       if (!$row->_entity->access('view', $user) && !$view->query->options['disable_sql_rewrite'] && $is_vapn_bundle) {
>         unset($view->result[$key]);
>       }
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> <sub>credit: [ash2303](https://www.drupal.org/project/vapn/issues/3058989#comment-13256022)</sub>

Comment: I'd like to clarify, for front-enders like me, that you can copy the code in your themeName.theme file, but you need to include this first: `use \Drupal\views\ViewExecutable;`