# How to ensure that node access check results are enforced everywhere?

Tags: 8, nodes, group

**I am trying to do this without `hook_node_grants`** because, for some reason, it messes with the nodes that are being controlled by the 'Group' module. The Group module itself used to use Node grants, but they got rid of all of its implementations [back in July of this year](https://www.drupal.org/project/group/releases/8.x-1.1).

For my use case, in addition to grouped nodes, I need private nodes that can allow for access based on field values. And right now to achieve this I am using `hook_node_access` in a custom module.

The issue with this is that it doesn't work for all the other things, like views and I do not know how many others there are. So, this I'd like to know:

Is there a way to do the access checks once and have them enforced everywhere? ( is hook_access_query_alter the way to do it)?

If there isn't a unified way to go about it? How many access checks should be implemented for a secure approach?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Having views respect hook\_node\_access](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/23225/having-views-respect-hook-node-access)

Comment: Sadly no. My question is about how to achieve the same thing mentioned in that question but without using that one method mentioned in the answers. I apologize if my question was not clear enough.

Comment: I guess you could do similar to [Exclude specific nodes from a view based on role permissions](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/297915/exclude-specific-nodes-from-a-view-based-on-role-permissions/297917#297917) and unset (remove) the view result row if user doesn't have view access.

Comment: I am using something like that, butlooking for a better approach, hence this.

Here is something that I have been looking at https://gorannikolovski.com/blog/query-level-filtering-custom-entities-drupal-8

Not sure if the same can be applied to node content types. and this too

https://www.prometsource.com/blog/how-override-entity-access-handlers-drupal

Would extending NodeAccessController do it?

Comment: Sometimes hook_query_node_access_alter can be useful, if you want to apply custom access control to node queries.